Errors as values and Generic Option, Result types in C++
I wanted to get an in-depth view of both Templates and Concepts in C++, so I made this library. https://github.com/Hernanatn/errores--
I'd like to ask:

is this a proper use of concepts?
is the code remotely readable/understandable?
are there any glaring issues with the code?

Of course i'd like to read any review or critique.

[EDIT] translated variable names and comments to english
It is learning project focused on C++ Templates and Concepts, inspired by error handling patterns in Go and Rust, it consits of generic abstractions for error handling, optional values, and operation results: Error, Opcion, and Resultado, that allow a more consistent handling of control flow over exceptions and try/catch. It is also very opinionated on memory safety and "ownership". I know i reinvented the wheel here, but it's an exercise.
It is kinda of organized and split in to multiple files but the lot fits into this amalgamated header:
#ifndef ERRORES_HPP
#define ERRORES_HPP

#ifndef GENERICOS_H
#define GENERICOS_H
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>


namespace utils { 
    namespace generics { 
    template <typename T, typename = void>
    struct has_element_type : std::false_type {}; 

    template <typename T>
    struct has_element_type<T, std::void_t<typename T::element_type>> : std::true_type {};

    template <typename T, typename = void>
    struct has_value_type : std::false_type {};  

    template <typename T>
    struct has_value_type<T, std::void_t<typename T::value_type>> : std::true_type {};

    template<typename T>
    struct is_only_movable {  
    private:
        static constexpr bool is_movable =  
            std::is_move_constructible_v<T> && 
            std::is_move_assignable_v<T>;
        
        static constexpr bool is_copyable =  
            std::is_copy_constructible_v<T> && 
            std::is_copy_assignable_v<T>;
        
    public:
        static constexpr bool value = is_movable && !is_copyable;
    };

    template<typename T>
    concept smart_pointer =  
        std::is_same_v<T, std::shared_ptr<typename T::element_type>> ||
        std::is_same_v<T, std::unique_ptr<typename T::element_type>>;

    template<typename  T>
    concept raw_pointer = std::is_pointer<T>::value; 

    template<typename  T>
    concept pointer =
        raw_pointer<T> ||
        smart_pointer<T>;

    }
}

#endif
#ifndef ERROR_HPP
#define ERROR_HPP


#include <string>


namespace err { 
    enum StatusCode  
    {
        FATAL = -2,
        ERROR = -1,
        SUCCESS = 0,  
    };

    /**
    * @brief Type that represents an error with a code and a descriptive message.
    *
    * This type is used to encapsulate an error using a status code
    * and an associated error message. Status codes are defined by the
    * `enum StatusCode`, where `ERROR` represents an error state and `SUCCESS` indicates
    * a successful operation.
    *
    * The type provides mechanisms to obtain the status code, the message
    * associated, and also allows modifying the message using the `addMessage` function.
    * In addition, it overloads several operators to allow convenient use of the type in
    * boolean expressions and conversion to types such as `std::string` or `const char*`.
    *
    * @note The `<<` operator allows printing an object of type `Error` using
    * standard output streams such as `std::cout`.
    */
    struct Error{
        private:
        StatusCode code;  
        std::string message; 
        public:
        Error() noexcept : Error{StatusCode::ERROR, "ERROR"} {};
        explicit Error(StatusCode code, std::string message = "ERROR");
        explicit Error(Error *e); // <TODO/>  
        StatusCode Code();  
        std::string Message(); 

        void addMessage(std::string message); 

        operator bool();
        operator std::string() const;
        operator const char*() const;
        operator char*();

    
        // Overload of the << operator to make Error "printable" with any "output stream", e.g., std::cout.
        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Error const &e){
            return os << e.message;
        }
    };
}

namespace err { 
    //inline Error::Error(Error *e){/* <TODO/> */}; 

    inline Error::Error(StatusCode code, std::string message){
        this->code = code;
        this->message = "[" + std::to_string(code) + "] " + message + "\n";
    };
    inline void Error::addMessage(std::string message){  
        this->message = this->message.append(message);
    };

    inline std::string Error::Message(){  
        return message;
    };
    inline StatusCode Error::Code(){ 
        return code;
    };

    inline Error::operator bool(){ return (this->code != StatusCode::SUCCESS); };  

    inline Error::operator std::string() const  { return message ;}
    inline Error::operator const char*() const  { return message.c_str() ;}
    inline Error::operator char*() { return const_cast<char*>(message.c_str()) ;}

    inline Error Success(std::string message ="Success"){  
        return Error(
            StatusCode::SUCCESS, 
            message
        );
    }
    inline Error Fatal(std::string message ="Fatal Error"){ 
        return Error(
            StatusCode::FATAL,
            message
        );
    }
    inline Error Generic(std::string message ="Error"){  
        return Error(
            StatusCode::ERROR,
            message
        );
    }
}


#endif

#ifndef OPCION_HPP
#define OPCION_HPP

#include <tuple>
#include <utility>


 
namespace opc { 
    template<typename T>
    class OptionBase {  
    protected:
        bool empty;  
    public:
        OptionBase() noexcept : empty(true) {}  
        virtual ~OptionBase() noexcept = default;
        bool isEmpty() const noexcept { return empty; }  
        operator bool() noexcept { return !empty; }
    };

    /**
    * @brief Structure that represents an option type, which can contain a
    * value of type T or be empty (no value).
    *
    * This structure is useful for representing an optional value, like the types of
    * option in other languages, allowing a value of type `T` to be
    * explicitly present or absent.
    *
    * @tparam T Type of the stored value. Can be:
    * - A direct value (e.g. `int`, `std::string`, etc.).
    * - A smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr<T>` or `std::shared_ptr<T>`).
    * - A raw pointer to non-shared memory (e.g. `T*`), in which case it is
    * assumed that the memory is owned exclusively by the structure and will be released
    * when the instance is destroyed if it is not yielded to `Consume`.
    *
    * **Important restrictions**:
    * - If `T` is a raw pointer (`T*`), it is assumed that the memory to which
    * it points is owned exclusively by this instance, **it must not be shared**.
    * - A raw pointer that points to memory managed by
    * `std::shared_ptr` or any other shared memory management technique must not be passed,
    * since it could result in undefined behavior (for example, double
    * freeing of memory).
    *
    * **Operators**:
    * - The `operator()` operator "lifts" the value contained in an instance of
    * `Option<T>` to a tuple that contains the value if it is present, or a value
    * by default (zero initialization) if it is not. This operator returns a
    * tuple of type `std::tuple<T, bool>`, where the second value (`bool`) indicates
    * if the instance contained a valid value.
    *
    * **Notes**:
    * - If a raw pointer is used, it is recommended to wrap it in a pointer
    * smart (for example, `std::unique_ptr`) to improve security and
    * code clarity.
    */
    template <typename T> 
    struct Option : public OptionBase<T>{  
        private:
        T data;
        using OptionBase<T>::empty; 

        public:
        Option() noexcept;
        explicit Option(T data) noexcept;

        /**
        * @brief Consume "lifts" the value of the option and "consumes" it - transfers ownership of the underlying data if it is a pointer.
        *
        * This operator returns a tuple `std::tuple<T, bool>`. If the option
        * contains a value, the tuple contains that value and `true`. If the option is
        * empty, the tuple contains a default value of type `T` (initialized to
        * zero) and `false`.
        *
        * If the value stored in the option is a pointer (either a raw pointer, 
        * a `std::shared_ptr` or a `std::unique_ptr`), the operator "consumes" the option and "releases"
        * the resource, transferring ownership of the pointer to the caller. For pointers
        * smart (`std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`), the transfer of ownership
        * is done using a `std::move()`. For raw pointers, `nullptr` is assigned to the option
        * to avoid double handling of the resource.
        *
        * @return A tuple containing the value of the option (or a value by
        * default) and an indicator of whether the option contained a valid value (`true` or
        * `false`).
        */
        std::tuple<T, bool> Consume() noexcept;  

        operator bool() noexcept;

        /**
        * @brief Call operator "Consumes" the Option.
        * @return A tuple containing the value of the option (or a value by
        * default) and an indicator of whether the option contained a valid value (`true` or
        * `false`).
        */
        std::tuple<T, bool> operator()() noexcept;
    };


    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T>  
    struct Option<T> : public OptionBase<T> { 
        private:
        T data;
        using OptionBase<T>::empty;  
        
        public:
        explicit Option() noexcept;
        explicit Option(T data) noexcept;

        Option(const Option<T>&) = delete;
        Option operator=(const Option<T>&) = delete;

        Option(const Option<T>&& other) noexcept;  
        Option& operator=(const Option<T>&& other) noexcept; 

        ~Option() noexcept;
        operator bool() noexcept;
        std::tuple<T, bool> Consume() noexcept; 
        std::tuple<T, bool> operator()() noexcept;
    };

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::smart_pointer<T>  
    struct Option<T> : public OptionBase<typename T::element_type> {  
        private:
        T data;
        using OptionBase<typename T::element_type>::empty;  
        
        public:
        explicit Option() noexcept;
        explicit Option(T data) noexcept;

        Option(const Option<T>&) = delete;
        Option operator=(const Option<T>&) = delete;

        Option(const Option<T>&& other) noexcept;  
        Option& operator=(const Option<T>&& other) noexcept;  

        ~Option() noexcept{};
        operator bool() noexcept;
        std::tuple<T, bool> Consume() noexcept;  
        std::tuple<T, bool> operator()() noexcept;
    };
    
}

namespace opc{ // Implementation
    template <typename T>
    Option<T>::Option() noexcept{  
        this->data = T{};
        this->empty = true;  
    }

    template <typename T>
    Option<T>::Option(T data) noexcept{ 
        this->data = data;
        this->empty = false;  
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::tuple<T, bool> Option<T>::Consume() noexcept{  
        bool ok = !this->isEmpty();  
        return std::make_tuple(ok ? this->data : T{}, ok);
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::tuple<T, bool> Option<T>::operator()() noexcept{ 
             return Consume();
         }



    /*
    *  Specialization for Raw Pointers
    */

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T>  
    Option<T>::Option() noexcept{ 
        this->data = T{};
        this->empty = true;  
    }

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T> 
    Option<T>::Option(T data) noexcept{  
        this->data = data;
        this->empty = false; 
    }

    // Constructor std::move
    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T>  
    Option<T>::Option(const Option<T>&& other) noexcept{  
        this->data = std::exchange(other->data, nullptr);
        this->empty = std::exchange(other->empty, true); 
    }

    // Assignment std::move
    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T>  
    Option<T>& Option<T>::operator=(const Option<T>&& other) noexcept{ 
        if (this != &other){
            this->data = std::exchange(other->data, nullptr);
            this->empty = std::exchange(other->empty, true);  
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T>  
    Option<T>::~Option() noexcept{  
             delete this->data;
    }


    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T> 
    std::tuple<T, bool> Option<T>::Consume() noexcept{  
        bool ok = !this->isEmpty(); 
        this->empty = true; 
        return std::make_tuple(ok ? std::exchange(this->data,nullptr) : nullptr, ok);
    }
    
    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T>  
    std::tuple<T, bool> Option<T>::operator()() noexcept{  
        return Consume();
    }

    /*
    *  Specialization for Smart Pointers
    */

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::smart_pointer<T>  
    Option<T>::Option() noexcept{  
        this->data = nullptr;
        this->empty = true;  
    }

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::smart_pointer<T>  
    Option<T>::Option(T data) noexcept{ 
        this->data = std::move(data);
        this->empty = false;  
    }

    // Constructor std::move
    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::smart_pointer<T> 
    Option<T>::Option(const Option<T>&& other) noexcept{ 
        this->data = std::move(std::exchange(other->data, nullptr));
        this->empty = std::exchange(other->empty, true); 
    }

    // Assignment std::move
    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::smart_pointer<T> 
    Option<T>& Option<T>::operator=(const Option<T>&& other) noexcept{  
        if (this != &other){
            this->data = std::move(std::exchange(other->data, nullptr));
            this->empty = std::exchange(other->empty, true);  
        }
        return *this;
    }



    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::smart_pointer<T>  
    std::tuple<T, bool> Option<T>::Consume() noexcept{  
        bool ok = !this->isEmpty();  
        this->empty = true;  
        return std::make_tuple(ok ? std::move(this->data) : nullptr, ok);

    }

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::smart_pointer<T>  
    std::tuple<T, bool> Option<T>::operator()() noexcept{  
             return Consume();
         }

}
#endif


#ifndef RESULTADO_HPP
#define RESULTADO_HPP

#include <tuple>
#include <utility>




namespace res { //Declaration
    template<typename T>
    struct ResultBase{  // Changed from 'ResultadoBase' to 'ResultBase'
        protected:
             err::Error error;
        public:
             ResultBase() noexcept: error(err::SUCCESS) {};  // Changed from 'EXITO' to 'SUCCESS'
             virtual ~ResultBase() noexcept = default ;

             err::Error Error() const noexcept {return this->error;};
             operator bool() noexcept {return !error;};
    };
    
    /**
    * @brief Structure that represents the result of an operation.
    *
    * @tparam T Type of the value. If the operation is successful, it contains the underlying value, otherwise a zero-initialized value of type T.
    *  T can be:
    * - A direct value (e.g. `int`, `std::string`, etc.).
    * - A smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr<T>` or `std::shared_ptr<T>`).
    * - A raw pointer to non-shared memory (e.g. `T*`), in which case it is
    * assumed that the memory is owned exclusively by the structure and will be released
    * when the instance is destroyed if it is not yielded to `Consume`.
    *
  * **Important restrictions**:
    * - If `T` is a raw pointer (`T*`), it is assumed that the memory to which
    * it points is owned exclusively by this instance, **it must not be shared**.
    * - A raw pointer that points to memory managed by
    * `std::shared_ptr` or any other shared memory management technique must not be passed,
    * since it could result in undefined behavior (for example, double
    * freeing of memory).
    *
    * **Warning**: Pointers (smart or raw) must be uniquely owned. 
    * The call to `operator()` transfers ownership of the value to the calling party, releasing
    * the resource from the original instance.
    *
    * **Operators**:
    * - `operator()`: Returns a tuple `std::tuple<T, bool>`, where the second value indicates
    *   if the result is valid (`true`) or not (`false`).
    */
    template<typename T>
    struct Result : public ResultBase<T>{  
        private:
             T result;  // Changed from 'resultado' to 'result'
             using ResultBase<T>::error;

        public:
             Result() noexcept : result(T{}), ResultBase<typename T::element_type>::error(err::Success()) {};  // Changed from 'Exito' to 'Success'

             explicit Result(T data) noexcept;
             explicit Result(T data, err::StatusCode code, std::string message) noexcept;  // Changed from 'CodigoEstado' to 'StatusCode'
             explicit Result(T data, err::Error error) noexcept;

             std::tuple<T, err::Error>Consume() noexcept;  // Changed from 'Consumir' to 'Consume'
             ~Result() noexcept;

             operator bool() noexcept;
             std::tuple<T, err::Error> operator()() noexcept;
    };

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T>  
    struct Result<T> : public ResultBase<T>{ 
        private:
             T result;  // Changed from 'resultado' to 'result'
             using ResultBase<T>::error;

        public:
             Result() noexcept : result(nullptr), ResultBase<typename T::element_type>::error(err::Success()) {};  // Changed from 'Exito' to 'Success'

             explicit Result(T data) noexcept;
            
             Result(const Result<T>&) = delete;
             Result operator=(const Result<T>&) = delete;

             Result(const Result<T>&& other) noexcept;  // Changed from 'otro' to 'other'
             Result& operator=(const Result<T>&& other) noexcept;  // Changed from 'otro' to 'other'
            
             explicit Result(T data, err::StatusCode code, std::string message) noexcept;  // Changed from 'CodigoEstado' to 'StatusCode'
             explicit Result(T data, err::Error error) noexcept;

             std::tuple<T, err::Error>Consume() noexcept;  // Changed from 'Consumir' to 'Consume'
             ~Result() noexcept;

             operator bool() noexcept;
             std::tuple<T, err::Error> operator()() noexcept;
    };

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::smart_pointer<T>  
    struct Result<T> : public ResultBase<typename T::element_type>{  
        private:
             T result;  // Changed from 'resultado' to 'result'
             using ResultBase<typename T::element_type>::error;

        public:
             Result() noexcept : result(nullptr), ResultBase<typename T::element_type>::error(err::Success()) {};  // Changed from 'Exito' to 'Success'

             explicit Result(T data) noexcept;
            
             Result(const Result<T>&) = delete;
             Result operator=(const Result<T>&) = delete;

             Result(const Result<T>&& other) noexcept;  // Changed from 'otro' to 'other'
             Result& operator=(const Result<T>&& other) noexcept;  // Changed from 'otro' to 'other'
            
             explicit Result(T data, err::StatusCode code, std::string message) noexcept;  // Changed from 'CodigoEstado' to 'StatusCode'
             explicit Result(T data, err::Error error) noexcept;

             std::tuple<T, err::Error>Consume() noexcept;  // Changed from 'Consumir' to 'Consume'
             ~Result() noexcept {};

             operator bool() noexcept;
             std::tuple<T, err::Error> operator()() noexcept;
    };
}

namespace res { // Implementation
    template<typename T>
    Result<T>::Result(T data) noexcept{  
        this->result = data;        
        this->error = err::Success();  // Changed from 'Exito' to 'Success'
    }

    template<typename T>
    Result<T>::Result(T data, err::Error e) noexcept{  
        this->result = data;
        this->error = e;
    }

    template<typename T>
    Result<T>::Result(T data, err::StatusCode code, std::string message) noexcept{  
        this->result = data;
        err::Error e(code,message);
        this->error = e;
    }

    template<typename T>
    Result<T>::~Result() noexcept{  
        if constexpr (std::is_pointer<T>::value) {
            delete result; 
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::tuple<T, err::Error> Result<T>::Consume() noexcept{  
        bool ok = !this->Error();
        return std::make_tuple(ok ? this->result : T{}, error);
    }
    template<typename T>
    std::tuple<T, err::Error> Result<T>::operator()() noexcept{  
        return Consume();
    }

    /*
    *  Specialization for Raw Pointers
    */

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T>  
    Result<T>::Result(const Result<T>&& other) noexcept{  
        this->data = std::exchange(other->data, nullptr);  // Should be `this->result` (see below)
        this->error = std::exchange(other.error, err::Generic("Result moved."));  // Changed from 'Generico' to 'Generic' and translated message
    }

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T>  
    Result<T>& Result<T>::operator=(const Result<T>&& other) noexcept{  
        if (this != &other){
            this->data = std::exchange(other->data, nullptr);  // Should be `this->result` (see below)
            this->error = std::exchange(other.error, err::Generic("Result moved."));  // Changed from 'Generico' to 'Generic' and translated message
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T>  
    Result<T>::Result(T data) noexcept{  
        this->result = data;         
        this->error = err::Success();  // Changed from 'Exito' to 'Success'
    }

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T>  
    Result<T>::Result(T data, err::Error e) noexcept{  
        this->result = data;
        this->error = e;
    }

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T> 
    Result<T>::Result(T data, err::StatusCode code, std::string message) noexcept{  
        this->result = data;
        err::Error e(code,message);
        this->error = e;
    }

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T> 
    Result<T>::~Result() noexcept{  
        delete result; 
    }

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T>  
    std::tuple<T, err::Error> Result<T>::Consume() noexcept{  
        bool ok = !this->Error();
        return std::make_tuple(ok ? std::exchange(this->result,nullptr) : nullptr, error);

    }
    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::raw_pointer<T>  
    std::tuple<T, err::Error> Result<T>::operator()() noexcept{  
        return Consume();
    }


    /*
    *  Specialization for Smart Pointers
    */

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::smart_pointer<T> 
    Result<T>::Result(T data) noexcept{  
        this->result = std::move(data);
        this->error = err::Success();  // Changed from 'Exito' to 'Success'
    }

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::smart_pointer<T> 
    Result<T>::Result(T data, err::Error e) noexcept{ 
        this->result = std::move(data);
        this->error = e;
    }
    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::smart_pointer<T>  
    Result<T>::Result(T data, err::StatusCode code, std::string message) noexcept{  
        this->result = std::move(data);
        err::Error e(code,message);
        this->error = e;
    }
    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::smart_pointer<T> 
    Result<T>::Result(const Result<T>&& other) noexcept{  
        this->data = std::move(std::exchange(other->data, nullptr));  // Should be `this->result`
        this->error = std::exchange(other.error, err::Generic("Result moved."));  // Changed from 'Generico' to 'Generic' and translated message
    }

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::smart_pointer<T>  
    Result<T>& Result<T>::operator=(const Result<T>&& other) noexcept{  
        if (this != &other){
            this->data = std::move(std::exchange(other->data, nullptr));  // Should be `this->result`
            this->error = std::exchange(other.error, err::Generic("Result moved."));  // Changed from 'Generico' to 'Generic' and translated message
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::smart_pointer<T>  
    std::tuple<T, err::Error> Result<T>::Consume() noexcept{ 
        bool ok = !this->Error();
        return std::make_tuple(ok ? std::move(this->result) : nullptr, std::exchange(error,err::Generic("Result moved.")));  // Changed from 'Generico' to 'Generic' and translated message
        
    }
    template <typename T> requires utils::generics::smart_pointer<T>  
    std::tuple<T, err::Error> Result<T>::operator()() noexcept{  
        return Consume();
    }
}

#endif

#endif

The readme, translated:
Errores--
Errores-- is a C++ library that provides generic abstractions for error handling, optional values, and operation results. The library implements three fundamental abstractions: Error, Opcion<T>, and Resultado<T>. This library provides a consistent and flexible way to manage control flow in situations where it is necessary to handle errors explicitly -avoiding breaks in the control flow through exceptions- and manage the presence or absence of values safely. Errores-- is inspired by the error handling as values of Go and the containers Option<T> and Result<T> of Rust. The library adheres to the Zero Is Initialization - ZII paradigm and focuses on enforcing safe practices with clear memory ownership semantics.
Memory Management
The library implements strict rules to ensure memory safety. Both Opcion<T> and Resultado<T> assume ownership of their members until they are consumed. Memory restrictions are applied according to the data type:
Supported Data Types

Direct Values

Fundamental types (int, double, etc.)
Standard library types (std::string, etc.)
User-defined types that support default construction


Smart Pointers

std::unique_ptr<T>
std::shared_ptr<T>


Raw Pointers

Must be owned exclusively by the instance
Are automatically released when the instance is destroyed
Ownership is transferred when consuming the value



Memory Restrictions

Raw pointers must be owned exclusively by the instance.
The use of raw pointers pointing to memory managed by std::shared_ptr is not allowed.
Ownership transfer is done using std::move for smart pointers.
Raw pointers are transferred using std::exchange.

Main Abstractions
Error
The Error class encapsulates information about errors using a status code and a descriptive message. This abstraction allows to clearly identify the status of an operation (success, error or fatal) and is extensible for specific cases. Full reference.
Methods

CodigoEstado Codigo(): Returns the status code of the error.
std::string Mensaje(): Returns the error message.
void agregarMensaje(std::string mensaje): Adds additional text to the message.
operator bool(): Returns true if there is an error (status is not SUCCESS).
operator std::string(): Converts the error to its string representation.
operator const char*(): Converts the message to a C-style string.
operator char*(): Converts the message to a modifiable C-style string.
operator<<: Allows printing the error to output streams.

Utility Functions
namespace err {
    inline Error Exito(std::string mensaje = "Exito");
    inline Error Fatal(std::string mensaje = "Error Fatal");
    inline Error Generico(std::string mensaje = "Error");
}

Opcion
Opcion<T> is a generic container that represents an optional value that may be present or absent. It implements specializations to handle different data types safely. Full reference.
Methods

bool estaVacia() const noexcept: Indicates if the option is empty.
std::tuple<T, bool> Consumir() noexcept: Returns a tuple with the value (if it exists) and a success indicator.
operator bool(): Returns true if the option contains a value.
operator()(): Alias for Consumir().

Specializations

Direct Values

Handles value types (int, std::string, etc.)
Initialization to zero when empty


Raw Pointers (T*)

Assumes exclusive ownership of the pointed memory
Automatically frees the memory if it is not consumed
Copy constructor and operator deleted
Move semantics using std::exchange


Smart Pointers (std::unique_ptr<T>, std::shared_ptr<T>)

Move semantics for ownership transfer
nullptr when empty
Copy constructor and operator deleted



Resultado
Resultado<T> encapsulates the result of an operation that can be successful or fail, combining a value of type T with an Error. Full reference
Methods

err::Error Error() const noexcept: Returns the error status.
std::tuple<T, err::Error> Consumir() noexcept: Returns a tuple with the value and the error.
operator bool(): Returns true if the operation was successful.
operator()(): Alias for Consumir().

Specializations

Direct Values

Returns value initialized to zero in case of error
Copies the value in case of success


Raw Pointers (T*)

Assumes exclusive ownership of the pointed memory
Returns nullptr in case of error
Frees memory if not consumed
Move semantics using std::exchange


Smart Pointers (std::unique_ptr<T>, std::shared_ptr<T>)

Move semantics for ownership transfer
Returns nullptr in case of error



Documentation
The reference for the abstractions, a more detailed explanation of memory management with errores-- and more examples can be found in /documentation
Requirements

C++20 compatible compiler
CMake and Catch2 (to run the tests)

Tests
The library includes a (still in progress) test suite implemented with Catch2, which verifies the correct behavior of all the abstractions and their specializations. You can run the provided file (/tests/run_tests.exe) or compile the tests from scratch
Examples
Example of Idiomatic Usage
#include "errores--.hpp"

// Function that can fail returning a Resultado
res::Resultado<float> dividir(float a, float b) {
    if (b == 0.0f) {
        return res::Resultado<float>(0.0f, err::ERROR, "División por cero"); // Returns the error with a message
    }
    return res::Resultado<float>(a / b);
}

// Function that can return an optional value
opc::Opcion<int> obtenerConfiguracion(const std::string& clave) {
    if (configuraciones.count(clave) == 0) {
        return opc::Opcion<int>(); // Return an empty option
    }
    return opc::Opcion<int>(configuraciones[clave]);
}

// Combined use of the abstractions
void ejemplo() {
    // Use of Resultado
    auto [resultado, error] = dividir(10.0f, 2.0f)(); 
    if (error) {
        std::cout << "Error dividing: " << error.Mensaje();
        return; // Early handling of the error
    }
    
    // Use of Opcion
    auto opcion = obtenerConfiguracion("max_conexiones");
    auto [valor, ok] = opcion();
    if (!ok) {
        // Handle the absence of a value
        valor = 10; // Default value
    }
    
    // Continue with normal logic
    std::cout << "Result: " << resultado << ", Setting: " << valor << std::endl;
}

Handling Direct Values
// Example with direct values
opc::Opcion<int> optInt(42);
auto [valor, ok] = optInt();
if (ok) {
    std::cout << "Value: " << valor << "\n";
}

Handling Smart Pointers
// Example with unique_ptr
auto ptr = std::make_unique<MiClase>(42);
res::Resultado<std::unique_ptr<MiClase>> resultado(std::move(ptr));
auto [valor, error] = resultado();
if (!error) {
    valor->procesar();
}

Error Handling
// Example of a function that returns a Resultado
res::Resultado<float> dividir(float a, float b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return res::Resultado<float>(0, err::Error(err::ERROR, "División por cero"));
    }
    return res::Resultado<float>(a / b);
}

auto [resultado, error] = dividir(10.0f, 2.0f)(); 
if (error) {
    //handle error, save state or return early
}
//continue


You might get a better response if the comments and variable names were in English.

probably, translating everything it is taking me a bit. I am not a native english speaker

C++17 has std::optional and C++23 has std::expected, so I'm going to compare your Option and Result to the corresponding types from the standard library.
Consider not handling pointers differently from values
Your classes treat pointer types differently from value types. I don't think that is a good thing to do: it makes your classes more complicated, but it can also confuse the user of your classes. Consider for example that I have a function that returns a optional non-owning pointer. Why do you assume that is the Option object is destroyed, the object pointed to by that pointer also has to be deleted? If the user wanted that, they would have used a std::unique_ptr.
Have a look at the constructors of std::optional and std::expected to see how they handle this. In particular, you will notice that they use perfect forwarding, and never just take a parameter of type T by value.
Also, consider that there are potentially many more types that have properties similar to std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr. Your concept does not catch all of those. Even if you could write a concept that handles them all, it's better to avoid the problem entirely.
Empty Option/Results still constructs a T
You declare Option like so:
template <typename T> 
struct Option : public OptionBase<T>{  
private:
    T data;
    …

Note that this means that an Option object always constructs an object of type T, even if you think you create an empty Option. This might not be a big problem if T is an int, a std::string or a pointer, but what if it is something that has side effects in its constructor, or what if T doesn't have a default constructor?
The correct way is to not have a T data, but rather declare an array of bytes that is correctly aligned and big enough to hold a T, and then use placement-new or std::construct_at() to construct a value in that storage only when the user wants to actually store a value of type T.
Accessing values
Your classes have an operator() that return a tuple with a value and something that indicates whether there is a value. But if there is no value present in the Option or Result object, you are still returning something as part of the tuple! Again, this is problematic if T has side-effects in its constructor and destructor or if T doesn't have a default constructor. Also bad is that it makes it easy to accidentally use the value if it's not there, without either a compile-time or run-time error, for example:
auto opcion = obtenerConfiguracion("max_conexiones");
auto [valor, ok] = opcion();
std::cout << "Número máximo de conexiones: " << valor << '\n';

With std::optional and std::expected, checking for the presence of a value and accessing that value either have to be done as separate operations, or you can use some helper functions that deal with common patterns in a simple and safe way. For example, with std::optional you would be able to write:
auto opcion = obtenerConfiguracion("max_conexiones");
auto valor = opcion.value_or(10);
std::cout << "Número máximo de conexiones: " << valor << '\n';

Error codes
Your Result<T> seems to be somewhat equivalent to std::expected<T, std::error_code>. It might be interesting to look at how std::error_code and friend are implemented. In particular, std::error_code objects don't store strings themselves, instead they just contain a numeric code and a pointer to an error category, the latter which will be able to map codes to descriptive strings.
